# Capture group certain number of times with regular expression but last group has remaining values

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string delimited by a colon and similar to this...

```
xvf:metric:admin:click
```

I need to capture three groups...

```
xvf
metric
admin:click
```

Or another example:

```
one:two:three:four:five:six:seven

one
two
three:four:five:six:seven
```

My current regex is just capturing each word separately, resulting in 4 matches

```
/(\s*\w+)/gi
```

Comment: capture 3 groups maximum everytime? What would you capture for this `one:two:three:four:five:six:seven:eight`

Comment: `['one', 'two', 'three:four:five:six:seven:eight']`

Comment: try this then: `/(.+?):(.+?):(.+)/`

Comment: You can use: `/^([^:]+):([^:]+):(.+)$/`

Comment: that works. If you post as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `String.match` and `Array.slice` functions:

```
var str = "one:two:three:four:five:six:seven",
    groups = str.match(/([^:]+?):([^:]+?):(.+)?$/).slice(1);

console.log(groups);  // ["one", "two", "three:four:five:six:seven"]
```

Answer (score 1):

And if it's possible that you get less than 3 groups, you can use

```
/^([^:]+)(?::([^:]+)(?::(.+)?)?)?$/
```

You can find an "explanation" of the RegExp [here](https://regexper.com/#%5E([%5E%3A]%2B)(%3F%3A%3A([%5E%3A]%2B)(%3F%3A%3A(.%2B)%3F))%3F%24).

Comment: This worked for me... `/([^:]+?):([^:]+)[:]?(.*?)?$/`

Comment: @bflemi3 oops, sorry, my bad. The previous version only worked for 1 or 3 groups, I've updated the answer (I forgot one `?`).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to capture the first two things before a `:`, then capture everything after

Here's the regex:

```
/(.+?):(.+?):(.+)/
```

In code:

```
var testStr = "xvf:metric:admin:click";

console.log(/(.+?):(.+?):(.+)/.exec(testStr).slice(1,4))
//["xvf", "metric", "admin:click"]
```

Comment: It'd perform better if you use `[^:]+` instead of the lazy `.+?`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using JavaScript, it'd make more sense to actually use `string.split` and later `Array.slice` and `Array.splice` for string manipulation:

```js
var str = "one:two:three:four:five:six:seven",
  groups = str.split(':');
groups.splice(2, groups.length, groups.slice(2).join(':'));
console.log(groups);
```